# How to chain JavaScript methods natively from an iterator?

Tags: javascript, chain

Say I'm using js methods that have the 'this' returned, so one can chain like such:

```
something.add({a: 'xyz', b: 123}).add({a: 'abc', b: 456});
```

How can I chain these on something from an iterator? For example:

```
$scope.bindings = [
     {
            key: 'up',
            func: function() {
                $scope.scroll(1)
            }
        },{
            key: 'down',
            func: function() {
                $scope.scroll(-1);
            }
        },
];
```

**---EDIT---**

The library I was using is [Angular hotkeys](https://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-hotkeys/). I wanted to ask in a generic way to help anyone else in a similar position.

I have:

```
var hotBindings = hotkeys.bindTo(scope);


  for (var bind of scope.bindings) {
      hotBindings = hotBindings.add({
        combo: bind.key,
        callback: function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            bind.func();
         }
      })
 }
```

This assigns the 'down' method to both keypresses. If I write out the code without the loop, using scope.bindings[index].key (for example) and chain the .add() method then it works. I also tried without "hotBindings =".

Please don't mention the scopve vs $scope as this is being passed into a link function in a angular directive - angular almost certainly has nothing to do with it.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you want here ...

Comment: I'll try to put a codepen together later today when I have time, I know it's a little abstract

Comment: It's not a duplicate, I already said 'this' is returned in order to create chains.

Comment: @BenTaliadoros Does it really `return this`, or does it return a new `Something` instance? In the former case, your code would work. Show us the definition of that `SomeThing` class (or link it in case of a popular library)

Comment: It does return this, I was using the angular hotkeys library https://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-hotkeys/blob/master/src/hotkeys.js#L538

Comment: I am updating my answer

Comment: @BenTaliadoros Then your code should work, even without the `hotBindings =` assignment. There must be something else about it. What particularly does behave unexpected?

Answer (score 2):

<strike>The only problem I see is the not working `for (var bind of bindings)`.</strike>

*Edit: thought it had something to do with the `for (var bind of bindings)` syntax and `var` v.s. `let`, turns out the provided code just works. I'll delete this answer if the real problem surfaces. Must be in the `Something` class?*

Everything seems to work:

```js
var Something = function() {
  this.data = [];
  this.add = function(item) {
    this.data.push(item);
    return this;
  }.bind(this);
};

var bindings = [{
  x: 'hi',
  func: function() {
    console.log("hi");
  }
}, {
  x: 'bye',
  func: function() {
    console.log("bye");
  }
}];

var something = new Something();

for (var bind of bindings) {
  something.add({
    x: bind.x,
    callback: bind.func
  })
};

console.log(something.data);
```

Comment: @RaxWeber thanks for pointing that out. Turns out everything works as expected? Ben, could it be the implementation of the `Something.add` method?

Comment: I looked into the source and it returns 'this', as expected. https://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-hotkeys/blob/master/src/hotkeys.js#L538. Updated my question

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what `SomeThing` is or what it's `add` method returns, but you can replicate the chaining by doing

```
let something = new Something();
for (const bind of bindings) {
    something = something.add({
        x: bind.x,
        callback: bind.func
    });
}
```

Comment: If Somethign was an Angular factory what would you suggest?

Comment: That would depend on the particular factory. In either case, if the `.add(…).add(…).…` chain works, this solution will work as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you do this a lot (perhaps using different methods than just "add"), you might consider using a helper function:

```
function chain(obj, ...calls) {
  for(let {method, args} of calls) {
    obj = obj[method](...args)
  }
  return obj
}
chain(new Somthing(), [
  {meth: 'add', args: [
    {x: 'hi', func: () => console.log('hi')}]},
  {meth: 'add', args: [
    {x: 'bye', func: () => console.log('bye')}]}
  ]})
```